# Using vue-router with vuetify components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuetify.js

I have created a vue project using vue ui command along with the `vue-cli-plugin-vuetify` plugin. By default it have Home and About vue components in the `src/views` folder with the defined routes in `src/router.js` file. And in the `src/App.vue` file there's this simple code

```
<template>
<div>
    <div>
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    </div>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>
```

which routes are working as expected but when i replace `src/App.vue` with vuetify v-toolbar component as below routes doesn't work at all.

```
<v-app id="inspire">
<v-toolbar>
  <v-toolbar-side-icon></v-toolbar-side-icon>
  <v-toolbar-title>Gift Shop</v-toolbar-title>
  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
  <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
    <v-btn flat to="/">Home</v-btn>
    <v-btn flat to="/about">About</v-btn>
    <v-btn flat>Link Three</v-btn>
  </v-toolbar-items>
</v-toolbar>
</v-app>
```

`src/router.js` file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './views/About.vue')
    }
  ]
})
```

`src/main.js` file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import './plugins/vuetify'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

`src/plugins/vuetify.js` file

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import 'vuetify/src/stylus/app.styl'

Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  iconfont: 'md',
})
```

How can i fix routes not working in vuetify components problem ? Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: You are missing the <router-view></router-view> tag in your code. Add it after </v-toolbar>